# How to go from contour CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE to contour CHAIN_APPROX_NONE

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, contour

Using `cv2.findContours()` one may create contours that are "sparse" (CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) or "full" (CHAIN_APPROX_NONE). How may I convert "sparse" contours into "full" contours?

I don't have the source image for my contours (shape is known though), only the contours, and they are "sparse" (CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE). From this "sparse" representation I want to resolve the "full" (CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) representation, so that I can use it to access the contour intensity from other images.

My makeshift solution (see code snippet) is to use `cv2.drawContours()`, which draws all contour pixels from a "sparse" contour representation. The result is an image and I am able to pull indexes from the resulting image, e.g. using `np.argwhere()`.

However, this extra step seems a little unnecessary considering that `cv2.drawContours()` presumably already had those indexes internally before drawing the resulting image. I guess what I want is a variant of `cv2.drawContours()` without the drawing part, or an option to output the "full" contour representation instead of the image.

Another issue with my makeshift solution is that it does not preserve the ordering of points from the original contour. I wonder if `cv2.drawContours()` is able to recreate full, valid contours internally before flattening the result to an image?

Is this functionality available from other functions in opencv, perhaps a more basic function used internally by `cv2.drawContours()`?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

# shape (Y,X)
shape = np.array((5, 5))

# sparse contour (X,Y)
sparse_contours = [np.array(
    [[[1, 0]],
     [[1, 4]],
     [[3, 4]],
     [[3, 0]]], dtype=np.int32)]

def full_contour_from_contour(shape, contour):
    # switch shape from y,x to x,y
    shp = shape[[1,0]]
    arr = np.zeros(shp, dtype=np.int32)
    cv2.drawContours(arr, [contour], 0, 1, 1)
    idx = np.argwhere(arr==1)
    # reorder Y,X -> X,Y
    idx = idx[:, [1, 0]]
    # reshape to contour layout
    rows, cols = idx.shape
    idx = idx.reshape(rows, 1, cols)
    return idx.astype(np.int32)

full_contour = full_contour_from_contour(shape, sparse_contour)

# output
# these are correct pixels, with pixels in sparse contour also
# part of the full contour. However, the full contour is not 
# necessarily correct or even valid due to 
# lost information regarding point sequence along the contour)

[[[1 0]]

 [[2 0]]

 [[3 0]]

 [[1 1]]

 [[3 1]]

 [[1 2]]

 [[3 2]]

 [[1 3]]

 [[3 3]]

 [[1 4]]

 [[2 4]]

 [[3 4]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours
it states that the difference between them is that CHAIN_APPROX_NONE stores every pixel, and CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE stores only endpoints of the lines that forms the contour. So you can simply construct the lines that joins every pair of consecutive vertices in your contour to get the approximation of the full representation. Each pixel that belongs to the line belongs also to the contour.

Comment: Thanks @Sushi! It sure helped with a better understanding of CHAIN_APPROX_NONE and CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE. I also posted a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948727/11753040) based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In line with [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56935828/11753040), here is a code snippet that seems to solve my problem.

```py
def full_from_sparse(contour):
    horizontal = np.array([1, 0], 'int')
    vertical = np.array([0, 1], 'int')
    diagonal = np.array([1, 1], 'int')
    def _get_points(p0, p1):
        # find all points on line connecting p0 and p1,
        # including p0, excluding p1
        # line must be horizontal, vertical or diagonal
        diff = p1-p0
        if np.max(np.abs(diff)) <= 1:
            # p0 and p1 are neighbor points
            # or duplicate points, i.e.g no in-between points
            return [p0]
        if diff[0] == 0:
            # vertical
            fac = diff[1]
            inc = vertical
        elif diff[1] == 0:
            # horizontal
            fac = diff[0]
            inc = horizontal
        elif diff[0] == diff[1]:
            # diagonal
            fac = diff[0]
            inc = diagonal
        else:
            raise Exception("points not connected", p0, p1)
        return [p0 + _fac*inc for _fac in range(0, fac, np.sign(fac))]

    full = []
    points = contour[:, 0, :]
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        _points = _get_points(points[i], points[i+1])
        full.extend(_points)

    # add points from last segment, endpoint to startpoint
    _points = _get_points(points[-1], points[0])
    full.extend(_points)

    # reshape as contour
    full = np.array(full, dtype='int')
    rows, cols = full.shape
    return full.reshape(rows, 1, cols)
```

Comment: You can obtain `inc` more easily by `inc = p1 - p0; inc /= inc.max()`.